How to make Buttons interact immediately Unity UI?
So, if I press the button and hold it, the button will "wait" until I get my MouseCursor or Finger of the button and just then the button triggers the code. How to make so that the code will be triggerd after any interaction?
I trided to use the Unity's InputActionsSystem, but i didn't quiet get it, so I decided to let how it was. Is there a way to interact to buttons immediately??? pls help
Here are some pictures:

There are many ways to do it. One is through script, which is already shared in an answer on this post, and another is through UI by adding another component, "Event Trigger", to the game object you have a button component on and then add new event type which will be "PointerDown" and then you can pass the reference if the script and call the Jump method. Sharing the steps with pictures below.


And you can also remove the button component if you don't want to show the highlighting of the button. It will work fine with just the "Event Trigger" component along with the image component.

I just wrote a class that handles the click event for you:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class InstantButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    [SerializeField]
    UnityEvent<PointerEventData> onPress;
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // Call the event with the click event data
        onPress.Invoke(eventData);
    }
}

You can attach it to a Button and then you will be able to subscribe events to it using the Unity's Inspector.
